# zsh completion: getting file names from a specific directory

Tags: zsh, osx, autocomplete

OK, a little background: I use a Mac, and I do as much as possible in the CLI.

In particular, I frequently pop in a USB stick, `cp` or `mv` a file over, and then immediately wish to eject (unmount and disconnect) it. This can usually be accomplished in a handful of keystrokes, except for unmounting it, which requires (in 10.7) going to an empty desktop space (usually two spaces away at least), selecting the disk, and pressing "command-e". Frankly, this unmount procedure is, by several orders of magnitude, the most time-consuming and tedious part of the process.

It would be far more natural and efficient to simply be able to type, say:

```
ej<tab> J<tab>
```

Say my USB stick mounts at /Volumes/Jefferson. What I would expect to get from my 6 keystrokes is the following:

```
eject /Volumes/Jefferson
```

This should run the command:

```
diskutil unmount /Volumes/Jefferson
```

So, I wrote a nice little function:

```
eject() {
    diskutil unmount /Volumes/$1
}
```

And a completion function to go with it:

```
compdef '_files -g "/Volumes/*"' eject
```

There is a problem with this, however. The `_files` function generates complete paths. Now, I could change the line in my "eject" function to `diskutil unmount $1`, and things would work, but then I have no ability to type the first letter of the mount point name, since the path starts with /Volumes/. For instance, if I type `J<tab`, I will get autocompletion for the files in the PWD. I would have to type `/Volumes/J<tab>` to get the desired completion.

So, is there a completion function which grabs filenames from a predefined, specific location, rather than generating complete paths?

I'd really like to get this down to 6 keystrokes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
_files -W /Volumes
```

See the documentation of [`_path_files`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fpath_005ffiles).

Comment: Perfect! I knew that had to be built in. Thanks so much!

Comment: So, how do I get it to autoload this completion function? I tried putting the `compdef` line in the file `_eject` located in my fpath. I tried it with and without an autoload line. I looked at several guides about completion functions and nobody covered how to do a real simple example like this, and nothing I tried based on any of their examples worked.

Comment: @marshaul You need to have `#compdef eject` as the first line of the file, then the real code. See under [autoloaded files](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Autoloaded-files) in the manual. If you didn't add the line at first, you may need to delete the cache in `~/.zcompdump` and restart zsh.

Comment: AH! Deleting `~/.zcompdump` did the trick. Thanks again!